# How to update child component based on the change in data in its parent component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, mapbox

I have a map component where I want to render custom markers. However, I want to make a connected component in order to manage my state using redux. The problem I have is that the marker does not update its position according to the map and stays in the same position as I move the map.

This is the map render:

```
  render() {

    const {viewport, settings} = this.state;
    console.log("htiiss", this);
    return (
      <MapGL
        {...viewport}
        {...settings}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
        onViewportChange={this._onViewportChange}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN} >
        { this.markers.map((marker,i )=>{
          const {name, coordinates} = marker;
          return (
            <MyMarker key={i} longitude={coordinates[0]} latitude={coordinates[1]} ></Bus>


          );
        }) }

      </MapGL>
    );
  }

class MyMarker extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {
      latitude,
      longitude,
      currentTimestamp,
      eta
    } = this.props;
    console.log("asdasd", latitude, longitude);
    return (
      <Marker
        className={styles.bus}
        latitude={ latitude }
        longitude={ longitude }>
        <div ><span>aaaa</span></div>

      </Marker>
    );
  }
}



export default connect(
  s => ({}),
  d => ({})
)(MyMarker);
```

How can I Make the MapGL component tell its children to update their positions?

Comment: can you show us the mapStateToProps method that you have written for `MyMarker` component. In your question you are just sending the empty object, but I guess there's more to it?

Comment: What props are passed via redux to `MyMarker`? If its latitude and longitude, why are you overwriting it in the top most render function?

Answer (score 0):

In this snippet,

```
{ this.markers.map((marker,i )=>{
  const {name, coordinates} = marker;
  return (
    <MyMarker key={i} longitude={coordinates[0]} latitude={coordinates[1]} ></Bus>


  );
}) }
```

`coordinates` is just a fixed value in marker. I'm guessing `this.markers` is an array of `marker` object?

Regardless, instead of passing fixed values for longitude and latitude props to `MyMarker`, move the `markers` to the Map's state. If that's not possible, at least move the coordinates to the Map's component state.

Then, pass the coordinates in the state. It would look like

```
{ this.state.markers.map(..
```

This way, `MyMarker` will change whenever the `coordinates` in `this.state.markers` changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the solution you mentioned, but I keep getting the same problem. The markers are rendering, but the problem is that the position of marker stays the same when I zoom in and out on the map. It does not transform the position relative to the viewport